# How to stop re.finditer at first end site

Tags: python, regex

consider the code

```
 import re        
    mystring = 'XYZABCDEGHIJEGIJKLMNEPABCFGDEQRST'
    print re.finditer[start.start():end.start()] for start in re.finditer('(?=A)',mystring) for end in re.finditer('(?=E)',mystring) if end.start()>start.start()]
```

Returns output :-

```
ABCDE , ABCDEGHIJE , ABCDEGHIJEGIJKLMNE , ABCFGDE.
```

where as i want the finditer to stop at first E
 to get out output

```
ABCDE and ABCFGDE
```

How to do that

Comment: Can you say what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want search for strings between A and E to stop at first E after A , and not the rest

Answer (score 1):

I think you want all shortest matches of strings starting with A and ending with E. You can use the regexp 'A.*?E' to do this: rather than being greedy like 'A.*E' would be it finds the smallest match. You can use findall rather than finditer to get the matched strings. Overall, you have code like this:

```
print re.findall('A.*?E', mystring)
```